# Transform INSERT query into table view equivalent

Tags: sql, dart, utility

An UPDATE query is easy to read, even a very long one because each column is just before its value.

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET FieldOne = Value1,
SET FieldTwo = Value2
WHERE...
```

And so on.

*A contrario* a big INSERT query is difficult to read because values are visually separated of the destination field:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(FieldOne, FieldTwo,...)
VALUES
(a,b,...)
```

So is there an online tool that convert a pasted INSERT INTO sql statement to a html table for an example ? This tool have to certainly parse SQL.

I'm a programmer so a package in any language that can parse SQL into classes can do the job too. The best would be in Dart language.

Answer (score 1):

This [page](https://beautifytools.com/sql-to-html-converter.php) allow convert from sql to html, csv, json, xml, etc. It has a convert button (to generate the html code on the right) and a preview button (to show the html table following ).

The page provides sample data: [image]

Maybe it is not the best option, because you need to write the create statement, then the insert queries and finally a select query.